# Link to a section of an html doc that's been loaded in a div

Tags: ajax, html, hyperlink, hashtag

My site has a "nav" div, with links to different html files, a "sidebar" div with static information, and a "content" div, which the different html files get loaded into.  I've also set my url base in the header. One of these html files is a long document, and I'd like to be able to include links to sections of this file.  So I named the section headers and used the hashtag to link to them:

portfolio.html snippet:

```
<BODY>
<a id="top"></a>
<header>
<a href="#pulseox">PULSE OXIMETRY IN ZAMBIA</a><BR>
<a href="#dengue">DENGUE DIAGNOSIS IN NICARAGUA</a><BR>
<a href="#retina">EYE HEALTH IN INDIA</a><BR>
<a href="#mas531">MAS.531 COMPUTATIONAL CAMERA AND PHOTOGRAPHY</a><BR>
<a href="#mass60">MAS.S60 HANDS ON FOUNDATIONS</a><BR>
<hr>
</header>
<header><a id="pulseox">PULSE OXIMETRY IN ZAMBIA</a></header>
<img src="pulseOx.PNG" width="500px"><BR>
lorem ipsum
</BODY>
```

And this works wonderfully when I've opened the html by itself.  But when it's been loaded into the "content" div within the meta html file, it tries to take me to `<myurlbase>#pulseox`.  How do I make the `<a href="#pulseox">` link refer to html doc within the "content" div?  I haven't set a base url in the portfolio.html file.

Here's my meta html doc, if that helps:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_test.css" />
<base href="http://myurl/" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#content").load("home.html");

        $(".nav-1").click(function(){
            $("#content").load("home.html");
        });
        $(".nav-2").click(function(){
            $("#content").load("about.html");
        });
        $(".nav-3").click(function(){
            $("#content").load("portfolio.html");
        });
        $(".nav-4").click(function(){
            $("#content").load("cv.html");
        });
    });
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="nav">
 <ul>
  <li><a class="nav-1">HOME.</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-2">ABOUT.</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-3">PORTFOLIO.</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-4">CV.</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
myname
<BR><BR>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Does your <baseurl> coincide with the current page? If so, the links should work. Otherwise, you might try adding the missing part of the url to your hash anchors (that is /missing/part#anchor)

Comment: the <baseurl> coincides with the metapage index.html.  If I add the missing part of the url from the html page in the div (portfolio.html), it opens it in the whole html page, not within the div.  Can I set the target of the links in portfolio.html to a div in index.html?